# Youtube video api plays muted, How to unmute it?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, volume

So since I'm a complete noob in Javascript, I tried fixing this problem by myself but I just keep messing it up.
Here's the code : `

```
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',            
      playerVars: { 'rel':0 , 'autoplay': 1, 'loop':1, 'controls':1, 'start':0, 'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque' },
      videoId: 'k1-TrAvp_xs',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.mute();

  }


    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {          
            event.target.playVideo();
        }
    }
```

So yeah. When I open this webpage, the video does play but it is muted. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could remove all this

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.mute();

  }
```

and

```
 'onReady': onPlayerReady,
```

Unless you want to do something when the player is ready.

EDIT: if you want to start the video later you could try changing

```
event.target.playVideo();
```

by

```
setTimeout(function() { event.target.playVideo(); }, 5000);
```

5000 being 5 seconds, change for whatever you prefer

Comment: Thanks ! One more thing, do you know how to make the video start playing but only after a certain amount of time ? Or like when the screen arrives at its limits ?

Comment: Edited my answer showing a way to play the video after x time. Not sure what you meant by "when the screen arrives at its limits"

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line

```
event.target.mute();
```

Comment: Cheers! Kind of embarrassed I didn't see it.